How to understand `std::string str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>())` in the right way?
I have read the Most vexing parse carefully.
I understand that in the code below S s()  would be treated as a function whose return type is S and has no argument.
struct S {
     S();
};

int main()
{
    S s();    
}

But for the code below, I really can't understand why extra parentheses around the first argument to the string constructor are essential.
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

std::ifstream t("file.txt");
std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

It's clear that std::string str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>,std::istreambuf_iterator<char>); is a declaration for a function who has two arguments with the type of std::istreambuf_iterator<char>.
However, for std::string str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()), there are (t) or () follows std::istreambuf_iterator<char>.
If std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t) could be interpreted as a function declaration in std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());, why not std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() be treat as a declaration of a function whose return type is std::istreambuf_iterator<char> and has no input argument?

"code snippet below does not compile since S s()..." Your above assumption is wrong. The code is well-formed and should/will compile with all compilers. Even though most compilers warn you about this, that doesn't mean that the program is ill-formed.

std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t) is not being interpreted as a function declaration, it's being interpreted as a parameter declaration (with redundent parentheses). I.e. it's equivalent to std::istreambuf_iterator<char> t.

@john If that is the case then it shouldn't matter what you name your parameter. I mean instead of t you can name it whatever but then the program won't compiler. See demo. The program is something different. I'll write an answer.

The actual problem is that OP've used parenthesis around std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t) which explicitly tells the compiler that we want it to be considered as an expression and not as a parameter declaration.

@user12002570 I think you misunderstood the comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Pc4zqnTPE (the OP seems to want to know why the brackets solve the most vexing parse, and does want str to be an object and not a function)

@Artyer Yes, that's exactly what I am saying. In particular, the answer is that because adding those brackets forces the compiler to interpret std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t) as an expression instead of a function declaration. I've updated the answer to make it more clear. OP does seem to be aware about the parenthesis around std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t) as they ask " can't understand why extra parentheses around the first argument to the string constructor are essential....". The answer is because the parenthesis forces it to be an expression.

@Artyer I've added a contrived example in the updated answer to make it more simpler how adding parenthesis make the construct to be considered an expression.

@user12002570 Your demo does not compile indeed. And  this new demo works while its output is out of expection. I think the ouput should be a function pointer.

@John No, the important point I'm making  is that we can't put parenthesis around function parameters. For example, float func( (int i) ); in just invalid c++ because we're not allowed to put parenthesis around function parameters. This in turn implies that float func( (int(i)) ); can no longer be interepreted as a function declaration because now by putting parentheses we've removed the ambiguity and now (int(i)) must be an expression. Check out my updated answer.


I really can't understand why extra parentheses around the first argument to the string constructor are essential.

Because the parenthesis around the whole std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t) forces it to be interpreted as an expression.
The reason for this is that function parameters can't be surrounded by parenthesis. Like for example float func( (int i) ); is invalid. That also means/implies that the construct (int(i)) inside float func( (int(i)) ); can no longer be interpreted as a function parameter. In other words, by putting the parenthesis you've removed the ambiguity and forced the whole construct to be considered as a variable declaration.

Here is another contrived example:
int i = 0;
          v--------v---->these parentheses forces int(i) to be interpreted as an expression
double f( ( int(i) ));  //this is a variable declaration




the code snippet below does not compile since S s()

The above  quoted assumption is wrong. The code is well-formed and a standard conformant compiler must accept the program(though they're allowed to emit some warnings).
Note
Note that putting parenthesis around either std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t) or std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() will make the construct a variable declaration because just by putting parenthesis around any of the arguments you've elimiated the ambiguity.

double f(int(i)) would be interpreted int(i) as a function whose signature is int(void) and double f(int(i)) is a function whose return type is double and its input argument type is a function. What I can't understand it why the extra parentheses in double f( ( int(i) )) could force int(i) to be interpreted as an expression?

Sorry, I am wrong indeed. S s() is well formed, and it's interpreted as a function as  expected.

@John Because we can't put parenthesis around a function parameter. That is, basically when we put those parenthesis then the only choice for the compiler is to consider it as an expression as now it can no longer be a considered a parameter of a function. That is why I said "forces" in my answer in bold. Perhaps I'll this as a note in my answer.

By itself, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t) could either be an expression that calls the constructor of std::istreambuf_iterator<char> with a single argument (t) or be the declaration of a std::istreambuf_iterator<char> named t (with extra parentheses around the name that are ignored, like in int (x) = 12;).
std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() is similar. It can either be an expression that calls the default constructor of std::istreambuf_iterator<char> or spell out a function type (which in the case of a function declaration would be an unnamed parameter which has type std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(*)())
When parsing any declaration in C++, the most vexing parse is that the compiler has to try to parse it as a function declaration first, and then only if that fails can it go back and retry parsing it as a variable with an initializer.
So, with std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());, after the parser gets to the first open bracket, it tries to parse a type name or declaration, but it can't since these aren't allowed to have extra parentheses around them. It then retries parsing it as a list of expressions to call a constructor with and succeeds.
You could just as easily have put the parentheses around the second argument std::string str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>())). As long as one of the arguments can't also be parsed as a function parameter, str won't be parsed as a function declaration.
Other solutions include:
auto str = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
// ^ Not in the form of a function declaration
std::string str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{});
// ^ std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{} is not a function type
std::string str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t), {});
// ^ {} is not a type name
std::string str{ std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() };
// ^ Not in the form of a function declaration


I wish you had pointed out the preferred uniform initialization syntax. If it's a construction/initialization/conversion, then the uniform initialization syntax is preferable over function call syntax.

1. If I understand you correctly, you said that functions aren't allowed to have extra parentheses around them. Does the C++ standard guarantees/requires it?  2.  Putting the parentheses around either the first argument or the second argument could ensure the compiler interpreted str as an object, why there is no need to put the parentheses around both  the first argument and the second argument(I know it's right to do so, I wonder why there is no such need)?

@John  The reason you don't need to put parenthesis around both the constructs(putting around one of them does the trick) because the moment we put the parenthesis around any one of them, that construct can no longer be a parameter of a function since a parameter of a function can't have parenthesis around them. For example, we can write void func( (int i) ). Thus writing void func( (int(i)) ) removes the ambiguity and forces it to be an expression. I've added this in my answer so that future readers know this.
